# write() argument must be str, not pyhdbcli.ResultRow

Tags: python, hana

i am using HANA HDBCLI Driver in my Notebook to connect to HANA Table ; the table contains VARCHAR large size column which i am trying to access using sql cursor connection.

This is the code , VARCHAR large size column is xml string and i would like to store the content of this VARCHAR XML String into XML File , this the code i have written .

HANA connection working fine , the below code redacted code.I am getting following error while loading resultset to xml file.

write() argument must be str, not pyhdbcli.ResultRow

Can you please help me here what wrong i am doing ; sorry i am newbie to Python.

```
cursor = conn.cursor()
sql="SELECT CDATA FROM _sys_repo.active_object WHERE   OBJECT_NAME LIKE  '%AT_VIEW%'";

    cursor.execute(sql)
    for row in cursor:
        print(row)
        cdata=row
          with open("ATTR.xml", "w",encoding='utf-8') as f:
            f.write(cdata)
    cursor.close()
```

Comment: does `print(row)` produce the expected output?

Comment: @Marc Gruita ; yes i am able to print this row perfectly fine as xml string

Comment: that means there's a `___str___` method for the ResultRow type. try `f.write(str(cdata))`

Comment: @Marc Gruita Sorry  i realized Python is   adding extra characters starting and end characters  for ex : Original XML is '<?xml version......../>'  Python XML is ('<?xml version......../>') and all new line  characters in between with \n; when i am saving in as xml file the new \n  is treated as \n character not new line

Comment: Result set is list of tuples, so you need to access first element of a tuple with `row[0]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The result of the `___str___` method may differ because of the encoding used.

To replace \n with a new line, call the `.replace(oldvalue, newvalue)` method on the string object.
In your case you need to replace \\n with \n (replace the escaped string "\n" with the newline character)

Something like

```
f.write(str(cdata).replace("\\n", "\n"))
```